# What was the main difference between df[:] and df[::] ? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

What is the main difference between df[:] and df[::] and could you please give me one sample example for regarding this.i was unable to understand.

Comment: pandas? pure python? what's with the requests tags??

Comment: Almost certainly multidimensional indexing in pandas

Comment: pure python: no difference

Comment: Can't test right now but there may be differences in regards to slices and views (the former making a silent copy) in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about `python lists` and not `pandas` dataframes:

Consider a list `l`:

```
In [301]: l = range(20,30)

In [302]: l
Out[302]: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

So, if you do something like :

```
In [303]: l[3:6]
Out[303]: [23, 24, 25]
```

This means, you want to extract a list of elements from `l` from index=3 to index=6(6 not included). So, it returned `23` which is l[3], `24` which is l[4] and `25` which is l[5].

**Note: `26`(l[6]) was not returned as `6` is not included in `l[3:6]`**

So, l[:] -- Would return the all the elements as no range was specified.

```
In [305]: l[:]
Out[305]: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

**For extended slicing:**

**l[1:6:2]**  -- Would mean, you want elements from **index=1 to index=6 with a step of 2**. Step=2 means, **increment every index by 2**

```
So, you should get below elements:
 l[1], 
 l[1 + 2](because the step we defined is 2), 
 l[1 + 2 + 2]( keep adding `2` to the previous index )
```

Now, previous index here is `5` and the limit we gave was `6` where `6` is not included. Hence, we get only 3 elements as mentioned above. Check below:

```
In [307]: l[1:6:2]
Out[307]: [21, 23, 25]
```

So, **l[::]** would also return the entire list, as we haven;t specified any range here.

```
In [309]: l[::]
Out[309]: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

You would need to practice slicing of strings in python to get a hang of it.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

```
sequence[start:end:step]
sequence[start:end]
```

':' and '::' represent slices of sequences. If start, end and/or step are omitted, then the defaults are used instead: 0 is the default for start, len(sequence) is the default for end, and 1 is the default for step.

So if, `df = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` then,

```
[df[::]==df[:], df[:] == df[0: len(df): 1], df[::] == df[0: len(df): 1]]

Outputs: [True, True, True]
```